# How can I make my recursion program to output factorial of a number more efficient?

Tags: python, recursion, factorial, coding-efficiency

I have made a program which outputs the factorial of a number by calling the function: factorial() which uses recursion to calculate and return the value. I have also included a loop to break the program when the User inputs the word "off". Please suggest any improvements

Here is the code:

```
def factorial(base):
    if base == 0 or base == 1:      
        return 1                                  
    else:
        return base * factorial(base - 1)                            


while True:
   base: int = int(input("Enter a base number: "))
   Result = factorial(base)
   print(f"The factorial of {base} is: {Result}")
   offf: str = input("Enter 'off' to terminate calculations: ")
   if offf == "off":
    print("Calculations Terminated")
    break
```

Here is the terminal:

[image: Output of my code]

Comment: Is that not plenty efficient enough?

Comment: @KellyBundy honestly that IS quite an unefficient way of computing factorial.

Comment: @KellyBundy: one doesn't need recursion to calculate factorials. A loop will likely be a bit faster, I think.

Comment: @matszwecja How so? Probably the result appears in front of the user instantly.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But does that matter?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, it does matter very much, especially since this recursive solution stops working around n = 1000. And nothing really happens "instantly" with computers.

Comment: @matszwecja: hm, python must be allocating a tiny stack. In ruby, an identical code starts failing at n ≈ 9350

Comment: @matszwecja They said nothing about it crashing for large n, so presumably they're not doing that. And even factorial(1000) takes only about a millisecond, that will feel instant to everyone.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Python has default recursion depth limit of 1000. It can be changed, but by default this code will always crash around n = 1000, so that's kinda "hardcoded" crash vs program running out of memory.

Comment: @KellyBundy: "But does that matter?" - apparently it does to Silent_Arts

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not convinced it does, and they didn't say why, hence my question. How about just waiting for them to answer? I'm really not interested in other people's guesses.

Comment: Recursion crashes when I input something around 1000, I think I shall simply use a loop then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While recursive approach seems like a natural thing to do, sadly that is not very efficient, as each call requires a separate stack frame to be created. It also causes problems due to Python's recursion depth limit, which means you this program will raise an exception for any `base` > 1000. Iterative approach (with loops) is around 2-3 times faster and avoids the recursion limit problems.

```
def factorial_iterative(base, acc = 1):
    acc = 1
    for i in range(1, base+1):
        acc *= i
    return acc
```

EDIT: Of course, this still does not beat built-in Python's `math.factorial` method, which gives us something close to 10x speed up.

Here are the results for base = 995 and 20000 calls to the funtion:

- recursive: 12.80487060546875 sec
- iterative: 6.284244060516357 sec
- `math.factorial`: 1.1593496799468994 sec

Comment: I suggest to measure `math.factorial` as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy here, probably incredibly over-complicated analysis of different ways of calculating n! and their effectiveness.

Comment: `math.factorial` also uses a different algorithm, which I think has better complexity. So I suspect for large enough values, it'll beat your Numba solution (I'm not familiar with Numba and I'm only on a phone, otherwise I'd test it myself...).

Comment: Wait... Is that simple Numba usage even correct? I just tried it (at replit.com I can, after all) and it claims 30! is negative. Looks like it only uses 64-bit ints.

Comment: Ooops, seems that it does in fact only work for whatever C types can handle. A bit weird that it does not raise any sort of exception though

Comment: Your Numba solution looking significantly faster than `math.factorial` btw was kind of a hint that something was wrong, as that should not be possible :-). (At least not with that simple algorithm.) It's why I checked. Btw you're overwriting the second argument and you could start the range at 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this thing also that will memorise the factorials

```
res_store = [1]
def factorial(num):
    try:
        return num * res_store[num-1]
    except IndexError:
        for i in range(len(res_store), num+1):
            res_store.append(i * res_store[i-1])
        return num * res_store[num-1]
```

Performance wise it will be very fast but it will store the result in list so it will take memory.
For factorial 3000 -> size consumption will be 26040 bytes.